# HP Fortify Pre compilation errors.(could not load file or assembly Oracle.Dataacess )

Tags: odp.net, fortify

I  try to analyze my .net solution with HP FORTIFY from visual studio .But I am unable  my web project and got pre compilation error message . I tried to trouble shoot from command prompt and got "could not load file or assembly Oracle.Dataacess ".

In my solution one of the project refers Oracle.Dataacess dll and that project is refered by the web project .I tried to use x64 version of the dll . But I still got the error .

Appreciate your suggestions to get rid of this pre compilation error .

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: Did you use the Oracle installer to install that Oracle DLL? It has dependencies that may be missing. You might try installing using the installer.

Comment: I am afraid I don't have permission to install .

Comment: There's also an XCOPY download you can try. It uses a batch file to move the dependent files. The bottom line is there are many files that are required to be present, not just Oracle.DataAccess.dll. I don't know anything about Fortify but it is possible this is what it is complaining about, if you environment does not have ODP.NET properly installed.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method of debugging precompiler issues is to add this command into the post-build event of the web project in Visual Studio, that way the error shows up in the error list.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe" -v / -p $(ProjectDir)
```

Another thing to keep in mind, if you have files that are not part of the solution but are part in the web projects directory, the aspnet_compiler will still read them.

I find this situation common when developers would excluded files from Visual Studio.  This does not delete them.  Or if they delete them, then delete through the Visual Studio interface but not from the underlying source code repository and they just get downloaded again on checkout.

An easy way to check this would be to turn on `Show All Files` in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer window.

Comment: I tried adding the command and I got could not load file or assembly Oracle.Dataacess. Two projects A and B were having any cpu as platform and these two are referred by web project . when I change it to x86 then I get "could not load file or assembly project A." ... :(